# Codeigniter: Extract partial data from a query

Tags: codeigniter, model

I have a small question pls:
Let's say i have a long query:

```
$this->db->select('*')
     ->from('x')
     ->join(...)
     ->where('y >',$id)
     ->where('z <',$nr)
     ->where(...)
     ...
```

How can i put into a different variable all where statements so i can use them individually but only using one single query?
Thank you.

Comment: you can store where conditions in array and pass that array to query.

Comment: $array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);

$this->db->where($array); 

// Produces: WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'

Comment: not what i wanted. I want the whole where condition to be stored in a variable. For instance i want to use in my controller what the first where condition produces. Hope i explained it clear. For example i want in a variable to store the result of the first where, in another variable to store the result of the second where.. and so on

Comment: you want to store the results of the where condition? or do you want to store the entire query? if you want to store the query why would you want to do that if you can just call that model method from your controller when you need it?

Comment: i want to store the result of every where condition if it's possible

Comment: you need to create different model methods. Each method should have the where query outputting results. In your controller you call each of these methods and store the results in variables.

Comment: but what if i need to join multiple tables and then apply multiple filters to that? i need to create a method for every single filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create different model methods. Each method should have the where query outputting results. In your controller, you call each of these methods and store the results in variables.
Why not do this:

Controller:

```
function controller_method(){
    $res1 = $this->model_name->get_where_results1($id, $nr);
    $res2 = $this->model_name->get_where_results2($id, $nr);
    $res3 = $this->model_name->get_where_results3($id, $nr);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_where_results1($id, $nr) {
    $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('x')
            ->join("")
            ->where("");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
function get_where_results2($id, $nr) {
     $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('x')
            ->join("")
            ->where("");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
function get_where_results3($id, $nr) {
     $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('x')
            ->join("")
            ->where("");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

---

UPDATE - if you wanted to use filters, i would this way:

Controller:

```
function controller_method() {
    $res1 = $this->model_name->model_method($filters);
}
```

Model:

```
function model_method($filters) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('x');
    $this->db->join("");
    if ($filters['filt1']) {
        $this->db->where("something", $filters['filt1']);
    }
    if ($filters['filt2']) {
        $this->db->where("something", $filters['filt2']);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I know it can be done like this but i want to create multiple filters applied to the main query result where i join multiple tables

Comment: if thats the case you would need to provide conditionals in your main query . i will update my answer

Comment: No problem, anytime. Glad I helped.